# How Can I add line(view) below each of the item name in bottom navigation view?

Tags: java, android

I want to add a line below each name of the items. How can I do this with bottom navigation view? The image has an orange line below the item name. So It should be visible for the selected item only. I have done with the Linear layout. I need to do with the bottom navigation view.

[image]

Please check with this image. I did with selector functions for this

> attribute app:itemBackground="@drawable/selector"

[image]

Comment: You can customize the items by setting "app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_nav_item_background" where `bottom_nav_item_background` is a selector that handles selected/unselected states and provides different look based on the state

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement the below code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#fd724a" />
    <size android:height="1dp" />
</shape> in bottom navigation items background.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Please check, I tried with that what you said. The line(view) appearing in the center. Please can you say how to overcome that?

Comment: Idk, add padding or something in the shape

Comment: Okay, I will try some code with drawable. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For do this:

[image]

1. Create 2 drawables, 1 whit and 1 without the under line

- Whit line:

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:right="20dp"
            android:left="20dp">
            <shape>
                <stroke
                    android:width="4dp"
                    android:color="@color/bottom_sheet_divider" />
                <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item
            android:bottom="4dp">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            </shape>
    
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

- without line:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="-41dp" android:right="-41dp" android:left="-41dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

2. Create a drawable whit drawable checked state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line_unselected" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

3. Add this drawable on the BottomNavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
--->    app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_line"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```